# wordpress jquery inclusion by default

Tags: wordpress, jwplayer

I'm using wordpress 3.3.1 and it seems that jquery is there by default, all i need to do is to enqueue the file through wp_enqueue_script function. What if i want to put this function inside another plugin that is already installed. For example, i'm using jwplayer plugin for wordpress now if i want the jwplayer plugin to enqueue the jquery file for me where do i tell it to do this, the main plugin file for jwplayer is named as jwplayermodule.php and it's at the root of the jwplayer plugin directory.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You enqueue jquery like so:

```
// Function to perform any things that need to be done BEFORE the header is called
function my_wp_init() { 
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}

// Enable the widgets, prepare the function for the head call, etc.  
add_action('init', 'my_wp_init');
```

The best place to do this would be in your theme's functions.php file.  This way, jQuery is always loaded in your theme.

ALTERNATIVELY, you can drop the same code into the plugin php file you mentioned - jwplayermodule.php